# How To Add Form Element in Controller in Social Engine

Tags: php, frameworks, socialengine

```
class Module_PhotoController extends Core_Controller_Action_Standard
{   
    public function nameAction()
    {                           
        $this->view->form = $form = new Modulename_Form_Fromname();
        $this->addElement('Text', 'sender', array(
            'label' => 'Send to',
            'maxlength' => '40',
            'filters' => array(
                //new Engine_Filter_HtmlSpecialChars(),
                'StripTags',
                new Engine_Filter_Censor(),
                new Engine_Filter_StringLength(array('max' => '63')),
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
$form->addElement('Text', 'sender', array(
            'label' => 'Send to',
            'maxlength' => '40',
            'filters' => array(
                    //new Engine_Filter_HtmlSpecialChars(),
                    'StripTags',
                    new Engine_Filter_Censor(),
                    new Engine_Filter_StringLength(array('max' => '63')),
            )
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Proper way to do this is to edit file that's in `/application/modules/Modulename/Form/Fromname.php` and use `addElement` to add specific elements to the form. Constructing forms in controllers isn't best SE programming practice.